# how to run a local script in remote server using expect and bash script

Tags: ssh, unix, expect

I want to make a script that will connect to a server and do some CRUD operation on the server and again return to local. I do not want  to upload the script to server..

I have made a script that will help to connect to the server but I am not able to do any any operation through the help of the script.

please make my doubt clear regarding the fact that weather its possible to run a local script (as in my case ) in the remote server.

If yes how please specify the script also for which I will be grateful to you .

till now my script is

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip neviss
set user user
set password 1234
spawn ssh "$user\@$ip"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r";
interact ( after this line any command is not getting executed) 
ls -lrt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh usert@server
expect "user@server's password:" {send "$password\r"}
expect "$ " {send "hostname\n"}
expect "$ " {send "ls -alrth\n"}
expect "$ " {send "exit\n"}
```

Not sure if it is the most efficient way of doing it, but it seems to work in my test.
(spaces after $)

Also, you can put this at the top of your script "exp_internal 1".

This will aid in the debugging process!

Comment: many many thanks sir for answering my query.but can you just explain more like how does it work and what i need to right at the

expect "#" {send "hostname\n"} i mean hostname .

please reply i am in middle of a problem .please help .

Comment: I tried in the above process its not working for me ...please help ....

Comment: Hey sorry for late response. From what I understand you are basically trying to tell the script what to 'expect' after issuing each command. So for instance after sending the password, you would be at a normal command prompt. Now where you might be having a tough time right now is at the pound "#" sign. If you are using root then use the pound "#" sign. If you are using a regular user then use the dollar "$" sign. Regular users use the "$" sign on their command prompt. I will modify the script above

Comment: Weird. I tested this myself just now and it doesn't seem to work as a regular user. If you do it as root it works as expected. I will keep playing with it.

Comment: Okay sorry I figured it out. Something stupid. Add a space after the "$".. "$ ". I also found something else very useful.. will add above

Comment: Thanks sir for everything but still my requirement is not fulfilled .plz help !!!

Comment: That's weird. Did you try the debugging? Did it show anything?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call Interact in order to send a command. Interact waits for your input instead.

Here's a working example for running a "test.sh" script in the remote server (also calling a couple of other commands just to illustrate the idea), which also solves the user/root different prompt problem. Remember to make test.sh executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set prompt "(%|#|\\$) $"
set ip neviss
set user user
set password 1234

spawn ssh "$user\@$ip"
expect "assword:"
send "$password\r";
expect -re $prompt
send -- "ls -l\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "./test.sh\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "sleep 5\r"
expect -re $prompt
send -- "exit\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let `ssh` do most of the work. Assuming your local script is a bash script and it's in a file named "local.script":

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip neviss
set user user
set password 1234
set script local.script

# here I spawn a shell that will run ssh and redirect the script to ssh's stdin

spawn sh -c "ssh $user@$ip bash < $script"

expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"

# and just wait for the script to finish
expect eof
```

Note that `@` is not a special character in Tcl, and it does not require escaping.